Duplicate modal doesn't close after reviewing 50 Staging Ground questions
Upon reviewing 50 distinct questions in the Staging Ground on one day, it is not possible to review any new questions there.
Now, when I vote to mark the 50th question as a duplicate of another question, the modal for closing the question as a duplicate stays open without showing any indication that the action succeeded (even though it works).
This doesn't happen for questions I am marking as duplicates after my 50th reviewed question.
Unfortunately, I don't have a screenshot since I refreshed the page afterwards.

I've kind of reproduced this before by trying to modify the redirect behaviour (to not redirect anymore) after making a review action. There's basically no code to close the modal once the action has been performed since they think there'll always be a redirect.

Well it seems there is not always a redirect which is weird given that the redirect seems to happen with other actions when that limit is reached. While I don't think this bug is important in any way, it's still a bug that should be documented on MSO.
